# Exclude web.config file from build artifact in azure devops, wed aap deploy on iis

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

I want to exlcude web.config file from my build Artifact, can i exclude in .net core build template in CI pipeline or in web app deploy task in shown in image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlHw1.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

able to exclude web.config and other files using:

-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=\web.config

[exclude file command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkSXs.png)

Comment: in the answer it's single backslash \, in the image it's double \\
in some places I saw no backslash, so what's the correct way?
Also how to skip all web.config, web.debug.config and web.release.config using regex?
Thanks